# chef cookbook keep installing the tar in /opt

Tags: node.js, chef-infra

Here is my nodejs_from_binary.rb

```
Chef::Recipe.send(:include, NodeJs::Helper)

node.force_override['nodejs']['install_method'] = 'binary' # ~FC019

# Shamelessly borrowed from http://docs.opscode.com/dsl_recipe_method_platform.html
# Surely there's a more canonical way to get arch?
arch = if node['kernel']['machine'] =~ /armv6l/
         'arm-pi' # assume a raspberry pi
       else
         node['kernel']['machine'] =~ /x86_64/ ? 'x64' : 'x86'
       end

# package_stub is for example: "node-v0.8.20-linux-x64.tar.gz"
version = "v#{node['nodejs']['version']}/"
prefix = node['nodejs']['prefix_url'][node['nodejs']['engine']]

if node['nodejs']['engine'] == 'iojs'
  filename = "iojs-v#{node['nodejs']['version']}-linux-#{arch}.tar.gz"
  archive_name = 'iojs-binary'
  binaries = ['bin/iojs', 'bin/node']
else
  filename = "node-#{node['nodejs']['version']}.gz"
  archive_name = 'nodejs-binary'
  binaries = ['bin/node']
end

binaries.push('bin/npm') if node['nodejs']['npm']['install_method'] == 'binary'

directory "/opt/nodejs/" do
   owner "root"
   group "root"
   mode '0755'
   recursive true
   action :create
end

bash "get the nodejs-#{node['nodejs']['version']} from nexus" do
  cwd ::File.dirname('/opt/nodejs/node-#{node['nodejs']['version']}')
  code <<-EOH
      wget http://#{node['nexus_ipaddress']}:8080/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/com/nodejs/node/#{node['nodejs']['version']}/node-#{node['nodejs']['version']}.xz
      tar -xvf node-#{node['nodejs']['version']}.xz
  EOH
end
```

but the node-4.6.0.xz keep getting installed on /opt instead of /opt/nodejs/node-4.6.0, or /opt/nodejs

Answer (score 0):

It is possible your archive was created with `tar -P`

```
   -P, --absolute-names
          Don't strip leading slashes from file names when creating archives.
```

Then it's possible it won't extract to current directory, you can list your tar archive by running `tar tvf node-4.6.0.xz`.

BTW. Instead of doing directory/bash block 'shenanigans', you should use [ark](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/ark) resource with `:dump`/`:put` action.

Comment: tar tvf node-4.6.0.xz untars in directory node-v4.6.0-linux-x64/

Comment: `tar tvf` shouldn't extract anything, it should show full path, I assume it's just a typo. If it realy shows directory without relative path (`../dir`), I'm out of ideas, it has to be something not shown in your code snippet. Maybe there is space included somewhere in your node variables?

Answer (score 0):

Not to directly answer your question, but if you don't want to do all this I have a poise-javascript community cookbook that manages all of this and more.

Comment: please do share your cookbook

Comment: It's all up on GitHub and the Chef Supermarket https://github.com/poise/poise-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
tar -C /opt/nodejs -xvf node-#{node['nodejs']['version']}.xz
```

did the trick
Thanks @Szymon